# User input in an expect script?

Tags: expect

Is it possible to have user give his or her input in between an expect script? Where the expect script starts and after execution. Inside a few expect cases the script stops and waits for user input and then continues. Is this possible if so how would I do this?

Comment: use `expect_user` from expect or `gets` from Tcl. Read the expect man page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

.....
different stuff for your script
.....



expect {
  -re ".*assword.*" {
    exp_send "random_stuff\n"
    exp_continue
  }
}
```

`-re` part this one matches string for expect to either wait for certain output

`exp_send` this will send content to prompt when above regex matches

`exp_continue` it will continue execution **VERY VERY IMPORTANT**